# how to assert if the api is fired from the Mock Service Worker with desired payload , while using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, msw

I have a react component that is want to test, which makes API requests.
The MSW is working fine for mocking the API request.

but, my component also makes some calls that do not have side effects like after submitting the form.

how to assert if the API is fired to correct URL and with correct data.
for example `expect(apiRequest).iscalledwithpayload(date)`

Comment: Please provide some code to explain your question

Comment: Have you tried spyOn ? https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname